# What would be a good way to implement Zelda like attack?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

I'm looking for ways to implement "attack" like Gameboy Zelda used.

A method I came up with is:

1. Create a rectangle near a player based on the direction the player is facing when every time attack button is pressed.
2. If the rectangle intersects with enemy(rectangle shape) then, damage the enemy and push it back.

Just like the following image shows.

[image: how I want attack to work.]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good idea. You could even implement different weapon ranges that way (different sized weapon rectangles).

Comment: Or you could simply test if there's an enemy closer than a given distance (radius) when swinging the sword. Both are viable and pretty common solutions.

Comment: Can you narrow down what the problem is? If it's just design indecision, you should just choose whatever you think works best (like you current idea). The way the question is written, I only see it generating a list of answers where each is no more correct than the last. Please add to the question to include what you've tried an what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The yellow rectangle is, in fact, nothing more than the bounding box of the sword, that is enlarged a bit to ease the gameplay.

Comment: @Byte56, using rectangle is working fine but I just wanted to know various ways to do it. sorry for the ambiguity of questioning. I try to edit the question.